# Remove consecutive positive/negative numbers from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

(EDITED) This is my current DataFrame:

```
         aapl         tigr        srpt
4   58.254690  2475.247525  131.665569
5   56.869882  2386.634845  140.016802
6  -58.709564 -2597.402597         NaN
7         NaN  2314.814815  145.539223
8  -60.786578          NaN -154.822728
9  -57.780089 -2283.105023 -140.646976
10  57.116747  2192.982456  130.992926
11  58.139535  2304.147465  115.074799
12 -54.942036 -2074.688797 -110.595001
```

I was wondering if there is any way possible to remove all but the 1st consecutive positive/negative number, such that the result is the DataFrame below:

```
         aapl         tigr        srpt
4   58.254690  2475.247525  131.665569
6  -58.709564 -2597.402597         NaN
7         NaN  2314.814815  145.539223
8  -60.786578          NaN -154.822728
10  57.116747  2192.982456  130.992926
12 -54.942036 -2074.688797 -110.595001
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
In [1481]: x = df.fillna(1)['aapl'].gt(0)
In [1487]: ix = x[~x.eq(x.shift(1))].index

In [1488]: df.loc[ix]
Out[1488]: 
         aapl         tigr        srpt
4   58.254690  2475.247525  131.665569
6  -58.709564 -2597.402597 -143.492610
7         NaN  2314.814815  145.539223
8  -60.786578 -2032.520325 -154.822728
10  57.116747  2192.982456  130.992926
12 -54.942036 -2074.688797 -110.595001
```

Comment: Hi, may I know if there is a way to apply this on all columns independent of each other? Because when I replaced the value in row 8 and in the 'tigr' column with NaN, then replaced 'aapl' with 'tigr' in the first line of code, the code removed row 8 as well.

Comment: @lurence It could be a case that when you do it for all columns, you might end up with no rows left in the df. Coz, you might get a different set of indexes for each column. This would complicate the question more.

Comment: I see. I was thinking to use the whole DataFrame in the computation because I was afraid if 1 of the columns have too many consecutive NaN values, it could potentially create a scenario where another column still has multiple positive/negative values.